# Difference between numpy dot() and Python 3.5+ matrix multiplication @

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, python-3.5

I recently moved to Python 3.5 and noticed the [new matrix multiplication operator (@)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465) sometimes behaves differently from the [numpy dot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) operator. In example, for 3d arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(8,13,13)
b = np.random.rand(8,13,13)
c = a @ b  # Python 3.5+
d = np.dot(a, b)
```

The `@` operator returns an array of shape:

```
c.shape
(8, 13, 13)
```

while the `np.dot()` function returns:

```
d.shape
(8, 13, 8, 13)
```

How can I reproduce the same result with numpy dot? Are there any other significant differences?

Comment: You can't get that result out of dot. I think people generally agreed that dot's handling of high-dimension inputs was the wrong design decision.

Comment: Why didn't they implement the `matmul` function years ago?  `@` as an infix operator is new, but the function works just as well without it.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

The `@` operator calls the array's `__matmul__` method, not `dot`. This method is also present in the API as the function [`np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html).

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(8,13,13)
>>> b = np.random.rand(8,13,13)
>>> np.matmul(a, b).shape
(8, 13, 13)
```

From the documentation:

> `matmul` differs from `dot` in two important ways.
>
> - Multiplication by scalars is not allowed.
> - Stacks of matrices are broadcast together as if the matrices were elements.

The last point makes it clear that `dot` and `matmul` methods behave differently when passed 3D (or higher dimensional) arrays. Quoting from the documentation some more:

For `matmul`:

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.

For [`np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D arrays to inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation). *For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b*

Comment: The confusion here is probably because of the release notes, which directly equate the "@" symbol to the dot() function of numpy in the example code.

Comment: [numpy.dot](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) :  matmul or a @ b preferred for two 2D-arrays; If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over the last axis of a and b.. etc

Answer (score 29):

Just FYI, `@` and its numpy equivalents `dot` and `matmul` are all equally fast. (Plot created with [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot), a project of mine.)

[image]

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import perfplot
import numpy


def setup(n):
    A = numpy.random.rand(n, n)
    x = numpy.random.rand(n)
    return A, x


def at(A, x):
    return A @ x


def numpy_dot(A, x):
    return numpy.dot(A, x)


def numpy_matmul(A, x):
    return numpy.matmul(A, x)


perfplot.show(
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[at, numpy_dot, numpy_matmul],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(15)],
)
```

Comment: Answer above is suggesting that these methods are not the same

Comment: That's why the answer starts with a FYI.

Answer (score 23):

The answer by @ajcr explains how the `dot` and `matmul` (invoked by the `@` symbol) differ. By looking at a simple example, one clearly sees how the two behave differently when operating on 'stacks of matricies' or tensors.

To clarify the differences take a 4x4 array and return the `dot` product and `matmul` product with a 3x4x2 'stack of matricies' or tensor.

```
import numpy as np
fourbyfour = np.array([
                       [1,2,3,4],
                       [3,2,1,4],
                       [5,4,6,7],
                       [11,12,13,14]
                      ])


threebyfourbytwo = np.array([
                             [[2,3],[11,9],[32,21],[28,17]],
                             [[2,3],[1,9],[3,21],[28,7]],
                             [[2,3],[1,9],[3,21],[28,7]],
                            ])

print('4x4*3x4x2 dot:\n {}\n'.format(np.dot(fourbyfour,threebyfourbytwo)))
print('4x4*3x4x2 matmul:\n {}\n'.format(np.matmul(fourbyfour,threebyfourbytwo)))
```

The products of each operation appear below. Notice how the dot product is,

> ...a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b

and how the matrix product is formed by broadcasting the matrix together.

```
4x4*3x4x2 dot:
 [[[232 152]
  [125 112]
  [125 112]]

 [[172 116]
  [123  76]
  [123  76]]

 [[442 296]
  [228 226]
  [228 226]]

 [[962 652]
  [465 512]
  [465 512]]]

4x4*3x4x2 matmul:
 [[[232 152]
  [172 116]
  [442 296]
  [962 652]]

 [[125 112]
  [123  76]
  [228 226]
  [465 512]]

 [[125 112]
  [123  76]
  [228 226]
  [465 512]]]
```

Comment: dot(a, b) [i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m]) ------- like documentation says:  it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b:

Comment: Good catch however, its a 3x4x2. Another way to build the matrix would be `a = np.arange(24).reshape(3, 4, 2)` which would create an array with the dimensions 3x4x2.

Answer (score 18):

In mathematics, I think the **dot** in numpy makes more sense

> **dot**(a,b)_{i,j,k,a,b,c} = [image: formula]

since it gives the dot product when a and b are vectors, or the matrix multiplication when a and b are matrices

---

As for **matmul** operation in numpy, it consists of parts of **dot** result, and it can be defined as

> **matmul**(a,b)_{i,j,k,c} = [image: formula]

---

So, you can see that **matmul(a,b)** returns an array with a small shape,
which has smaller memory consumption and make more sense in applications.
In particular, combining with [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), you can get

> **matmul**(a,b)_{i,j,k,l} = [image: formula]

for example.

---

From the above two definitions, you can see the requirements to use those two operations. Assume **a.shape=(s1,s2,s3,s4)** and **b.shape=(t1,t2,t3,t4)**

- To use **dot(a,b)** you need

1. **t3=s4**;

- To use **matmul(a,b)** you need

1. **t3=s4**
2. **t2=s2**, or one of t2 and s2 is 1
3. **t1=s1**, or one of t1 and s1 is 1

---

Use the following piece of code to convince yourself.

```
import numpy as np
for it in range(10000):
    a = np.random.rand(5,6,2,4)
    b = np.random.rand(6,4,3)
    c = np.matmul(a,b)
    d = np.dot(a,b)
    #print ('c shape: ', c.shape,'d shape:', d.shape)
    
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(6):
            for k in range(2):
                for l in range(3):
                    if c[i,j,k,l] != d[i,j,k,j,l]:
                        print (it,i,j,k,l,c[i,j,k,l]==d[i,j,k,j,l])  # you will not see them
```

Comment: `np.matmul` also gives the dot product on vectors and the matrix product on matrices.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a comparison with [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to show how the indices are projected

```
np.allclose(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ijk', a,b), a*b)        # True 
np.allclose(np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', a,b), a@b)        # True
np.allclose(np.einsum('ijk,lkm->ijlm',a,b), a.dot(b))   # True
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience with MATMUL and DOT

I was constantly getting "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (200, 1), indices imply (200, 3)" when trying to use MATMUL. I wanted a quick workaround and found DOT to deliver the same functionality. I don't get any error using DOT. I get the correct answer

with MATMUL

```
X.shape
>>>(200, 3)

type(X)

>>>pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

w

>>>array([0.37454012, 0.95071431, 0.73199394])

YY = np.matmul(X,w)

>>>  ValueError: Shape of passed values is (200, 1), indices imply (200, 3)"
```

with DOT

```
YY = np.dot(X,w)
# no error message
YY
>>>array([ 2.59206877,  1.06842193,  2.18533396,  2.11366346,  0.28505879, …

YY.shape

>>> (200, )
```

Comment: `np.dot` is converting the dataframe to array, and returning an array, (200,3) witth (3,)=.(200,).  The error with `matmul` is produced by pandas, which is trying make a 3 column frame from that array.  I suspect a full traceback will show that.