# numpy Matrix Multiplication Simplification - is it possible?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Is there a way to simplify

```
 a=np.dot(a,b)
```

just like the way you write `a=a+b` as `a+=b` ? (`a,b` are both `np.array`)

Comment: Nope.  There isn't a shortcut here ...

Comment: You could create a wrapper class around `numpy.matrix` and overload the `*` operator, but that'd be very confusing and definitely discouraged. What's wrong with `np.dot`?

Comment: Well, I am just trying to save my runtime since a and b could be large in size.

Comment: What is the run time savings of `+=` for your size of arrays?

Comment: @Rushy Panchal What's wrong with it is that it uses six characters to express what should be done with a single character.  In a lengthier calculation, it's just plain tedious to read all those "np.dot".  It slows one's brain down from taking in the meaning of the equation.

Answer (score 15):

In Python3.5+ you can use the [`@` operator](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) for matrix multiplication, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(4, 10)
b = np.random.randn(10, 5)

c = a @ b
```

This is equivalent to calling `c = np.matmul(a, b)`. Inplace matrix multiplication (`@=`) is not yet supported (and doesn't make sense in most cases anyway, since the output usually has different dimensions to the first input).

Also note that [`np.matmul`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) (and `@`) will behave differently to [`np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) when one or more of the input arrays has >2 dimensions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34142617/1461210)).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using python 2.7 currently. But thank you for your reply!