# numpy Matrix Multiplication n x m * m x p = n x p

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply two numpy arrays as matrices. I expect that if `A` is an `n x m` matrix and `B` is an `m x p` matrix, then `A*B` yields an `n x p` matrix.

This code creates a 5x3 matrix and a 3x1 matrix, as verified by the `shape` property. I was careful to create both arrays in two dimensions. The final line performs the multiplication, and I expect a 5x1 matrix.

```
A = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5]])
print(A)
print(A.shape)
B = np.array([[2],[3],[4]])
print(B)
print(B.shape)
print(A*B)
```

Result

```
[[1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]
 [4 4 4]
 [5 5 5]]
(5, 3)
[[2]
 [3]
 [4]]
(3, 1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-653ff6c66fb7> in <module>()
      5 print(B)
      6 print(B.shape)
----> 7 print(A*B)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,3) (3,1)
```

Even the exception message indicates that the inner dimensions (3 and 3) match. Why did multiplication throw an exception? How should I generate a 5x1 matrix?

I am using Python 3.6.2 and Jupyter Notebook server 5.2.2.

Comment: If you want matrix-multiplication, you either need to do ```A.dot(B)``` or use the [new operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142485/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-python-3-5-matrix-multiplication) introduced. This behaves differently if A would be of type np.matrix or a scipy sparse matrix (where A*B is actually matrix-multiplication) [numpy-docs: basic operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` operator provides elementwise multiplication, which requires that the arrays are the same shape, or are ['broadcastable'](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

For the dot product, use `A.dot(B)` or in many cases you can use `A @ B` (in Python 3.5; [read how it differs from `dot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142485/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-python-3-5-matrix-multiplication).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5]])
>>> B = np.array([[2],[3],[4]])
>>> A @ B
array([[ 9],
       [18],
       [27],
       [36],
       [45]])
```

For even more options, especially for handling higher dimensional arrays, there's also [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html).