# How can I vectorize the dot product in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, dot-product

I want to compute *N* group of the dot product, for each group suppose it was a (4,3) matrix, called x_i. So I vectorize these *N* matrices into a (N,4,3) matrix, such as:

```
 [[[1,2,3],
   [4,5,6],
   [7,8,9],
   [0,1,2]],
     ...
   [7,2,2],
   [4,2,4],
   [7,1,9],
   [3,1,2]]].  #  #N matrices
```

If I compute each dot product of x_i and x_i.T individually:

```
np.dot(x_i, x_i.T)
```

It will get a (4,4) matrix.

But how to compute these after vectorization?

The final result should be (N,4,4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [31]: x = np.arange(5*12).reshape(5,4,3)
In [32]: x@x.transpose(0,2,1)
Out[32]: 
array([[[    5,    14,    23,    32],
        [   14,    50,    86,   122],
        [   23,    86,   149,   212],
        [   32,   122,   212,   302]],

       [[  509,   626,   743,   860],
        [  626,   770,   914,  1058],
        [  743,   914,  1085,  1256],
        [  860,  1058,  1256,  1454]],

       [[ 1877,  2102,  2327,  2552],
        [ 2102,  2354,  2606,  2858],
        [ 2327,  2606,  2885,  3164],
        [ 2552,  2858,  3164,  3470]],

       [[ 4109,  4442,  4775,  5108],
        [ 4442,  4802,  5162,  5522],
        [ 4775,  5162,  5549,  5936],
        [ 5108,  5522,  5936,  6350]],

       [[ 7205,  7646,  8087,  8528],
        [ 7646,  8114,  8582,  9050],
        [ 8087,  8582,  9077,  9572],
        [ 8528,  9050,  9572, 10094]]])
In [33]: _.shape
Out[33]: (5, 4, 4)
```

checking

```
In [34]: x[0,...].dot(x[0,...].T)
Out[34]: 
array([[  5,  14,  23,  32],
       [ 14,  50,  86, 122],
       [ 23,  86, 149, 212],
       [ 32, 122, 212, 302]])
```

---

`@` or `matmul` does a dot product on the last 2 dimensions, while treating the first, as you do, as the 'i' dimension.

`x.tanspose(0,2,1)` switches the last 2 dimensions, leaving the first unchanged.  For a 2d array `x.transpose()` is `x.transpose(1,0)`.  It is what you expressed as `x_i.T`.

As with `dot`, the key for `a@b`, is that the last dimension of `a` works with the 2nd to the last dimension of `b`.

Comment: Thanks for your helping, I am not familiar with x@x.transpose(0,2,1). But I notice that it work too!! I will take a look in the document and check why. Thanks again

Comment: I added a few notes.

Comment: Very clearly explanation!! I now understand it, thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

[np.matmul](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) will do the trick:

```
N=2; m=4; n=3
x = np.ones((N,m,n))
np.matmul(x,x.transpose(0,2,1))

array([[[3., 3., 3., 3.],
    [3., 3., 3., 3.],
    [3., 3., 3., 3.],
    [3., 3., 3., 3.]],

   [[3., 3., 3., 3.],
    [3., 3., 3., 3.],
    [3., 3., 3., 3.],
    [3., 3., 3., 3.]]])
```

Shape checking:

```
np.matmul(x,x.reshape((N,n,m))).shape
```

> (2, 4, 4)

P.S., as hpaulj mentioned in the comment this solution is basically equivalent to his!

Comment: `matmul` can be expressed as the `@` operator.  `reshape` is the not the same as transpose.  Your code works because your `x` is all ones.

Comment: Thanks you!! This is what I am looking for! I got the same result using this method to vectorize as using a loop. But now, I am wonder when to use np.matmul or np.dot.

Comment: @Yan-JenHuang this answer can probably help you to understand the differences between dot and matmul: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142485/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-python-3-5-matrix-multiplication

Answer (score 1):

seems that `np.einsum` could do this

```
x = np.arange(5*12).reshape(5,4,3)
np.einsum("nik, njk->nij", x, x)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can generate a 3D list. I would have make it like:

```
N=[]
for n in range (len(N)):
    N.append(n,np.dot(x_i, x_i.T))
```

Comment: You shouldn't name variables as `list` since that's a builtin and it's not vectorized because you're using a `for` loop.

Comment: I understand your point about names, but why you say it is nor vectorizable?