# Using inverse matrix function "inv" in python numpy.linalg

Tags: python, matrix

I'm using the inverse matrix function `inv()` in Python.
Im calculating the inverse of a 3x3 matrix, but when I multiply the result with the original matrix, I don't get the unity matrix, why?

Example:

```
AA = [[1,6,5],[2,3,1],[1,1,7]]

>>> inv(AA)
array([[-0.31746032,  0.58730159,  0.14285714],
[ 0.20634921, -0.03174603, -0.14285714],
[ 0.01587302, -0.07936508,  0.14285714]])

>>> inv(AA) * AA
array([[-0.31746032,  3.52380952,  0.71428571],
[ 0.41269841, -0.0952381 , -0.14285714],
[ 0.01587302, -0.07936508,  1.        ]])

>>> inv(AA) * AA
array([[-0.31746032,  3.52380952,  0.71428571],
[ 0.41269841, -0.0952381 , -0.14285714],
[ 0.01587302, -0.07936508,  1.        ]])
```

...which is not the unity matrix I. What am I missing?

Comment: `print(np.dot(inv(AA),AA))` gives you the unity matrix. This is not Matlab, the `*` operator is element by element multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing element-wise multiplication, not matrix multiplication.
Change your code to `np.matmul(inv(AA), AA)` or `np.dot(inv(AA), AA)` and you'll get the correct result

Answer (score 1):

[Python 3.5 introduced a new operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465) for [matrix multiplication](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/), so this could be:

```
from numpy.linalg import inv

AA = [[1,6,5],[2,3,1],[1,1,7]]

inv(AA) @ AA
```

which gives me:

```
array([[ 1.00000000e+00,  2.77555756e-17, -1.11022302e-16],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  1.11022302e-16],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

which is about as close to unity as can be expected.

maybe relevant, see [differences between `@` and `dot`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34142485/1358308) and other questions/answers linked there.