# Differences between the "@" operator and np.matmul()

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Is there an advantage to using the `@` operator over `numpy.matmul` when multiplying vectors, matrices, etc? Is this mainly for readability? Whats is the convention?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between numpy dot() and Python 3.5+ matrix multiplication @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142485/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-python-3-5-matrix-multiplication)

Comment: Basically the same as the choice between `np.add` and `+`, or `np.multiply` and `*`.

Comment: `@` was added precisely because [the Numpy community wanted an infix operator to replace explicit use of `matmul`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/#motivation).

Answer (score 9):

As the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) explains:
*The matmul function implements the semantics of the @ operator introduced in Python 3.5 following PEP465.*

So basically, `@` is the same as `np.matmul` without method parameters.