# How come python do multiplication of two 4x1 matrices with same shape

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I just realized that python does the multiplication of two matrices of 4x1, but as I know it is not possible two multiply a 4x1 matrix with another 4x1 matrix. I wrote the following code to test this:

```
import numpy as np

first_four_by_one = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4]])
print(first_four_by_one.shape)

second_four_by_one = np.array([[4], [5], [6], [7]])
print(second_four_by_one.shape)

result = first_four_by_one * second_four_by_one
print(result.shape)
print(result)
```

and the result is as follows:

```
(4, 1)
(4, 1)
(4, 1)
[[ 4]
 [10]
 [18]
 [28]]
```

can anyone describe this please?

Comment: This is an element-wise multiplication. The mathematical matrix multiplication got its own operator `@` in newer Python versions.

Comment: Well, this is not matrix multiplication. It is just multiplying all members of the two arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are acually performing an element-wise matrix multiplication. To perform a matrix mutliplication, you should use the numpy function `np.dot()`.

For 2D matrices you can use also the `@` operator which stand for `np.matmul()`. As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142485/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-python-3-5-matrix-multiplication), this operator can lead to side effects when working with higher dimension matrices (>2D)