# Gradient descent for linear regression with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I want to implement gradient descent with numpy for linear regression but I have some error in this code:

```
import numpy as np

# Code Example
rng = np.random.RandomState(10)
X = 10*rng.rand(1000, 5) # feature matrix
y = 0.9 + np.dot(X, [2.2, 4, -4, 1, 2]) # target vector

# GD implementation for linear regression
def GD(X, y, eta=0.1, n_iter=20):
    theta = np.zeros((X.shape[0], X.shape[1]))
    for i in range(n_iter):
        grad = 2 * np.mean((np.dot(theta.T, X) - y) * X)
        theta = theta - eta * grad
    return theta

# SGD implementation for linear regression
def SGD(X, y, eta=0.1, n_iter=20):
    theta = np.zeros(1, X.shape[1])
    for i in range(n_iter):
        for j in range(X.shape[0]):
            grad = 2 * np.mean((np.dot(theta.T, X[j,:]) - y[j]) * X[j,:])
            theta = theta - eta * grad
    return theta

# MSE loss for linear regression with numpy
def MSE(X, y, theta):
    return np.mean((X.dot(theta.T) - y)**2)

# linear regression with GD and MSE with numpy
theta_gd = GD(X, y)
theta_sgd = SGD(X, y)

print('MSE with GD: ', MSE(X, y, theta_gd))
print('MSE with SGD: ', MSE(X, y, theta_sgd))
```

The error is

```
grad = 2 * np.mean((np.dot(theta.T, X) - y) * X)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,5) (1000,)
```

and I can't solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `np.dot(theta.T, X).shape` is (5,5), but `y.shape` is (1000,). They can't be [broadcast together](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to do the subtraction (because of their shapes). To solve this problem you have to understand what you are trying to do with these operations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know what do you want to say and I have problem with gradient descent for linear regression and my question is not a code problem.
I have question about my math and machine learning problem

Comment: note that in your code `np.zeros((X.shape[0], X.shape[1]))` is equivalent to just `np.zeros(X.shape)`

Answer (score 1):

Minor changes in your code that resolve dimensionality issues during matrix multiplication make the code run successfully. In particular, note that a linear regression on a design matrix `X` of dimension `Nxk` has a parameter *vector* `theta` of size `k`.

In addition, I'd suggest some changes in `SGD()` that make it a proper *stochastic* gradient descent. Namely, evaluating the gradient over random subsets of the data realized as realized by randomly partitioning the index set of the train data with [`np.random.shuffle()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) and looping through it. The `batch_size` determines the size of each subset after which the parameter estimate is updated. The argument `seed` ensures reproducibility.

```py
# GD implementation for linear regression
def GD(X, y, eta=0.001, n_iter=100):
    theta = np.zeros(X.shape[1])
    for i in range(n_iter):
        for j in range(X.shape[0]):
            grad = (2 * np.mean(X[j,:] @ theta - y[j]) * X[j,:])  # changed line
            theta -= eta * grad
    return theta

# SGD implementation for linear regression
def SGD(X, y, eta=0.001, n_iter=1000, batch_size=25, seed=7678):
    theta = np.zeros(X.shape[1])
    indexSet = list(range(len(X)))
    np.random.seed(seed)
    for i in range(n_iter):
        np.random.shuffle(indexSet) # random shuffle of index set
        for j in range(round(len(X) / batch_size)+1):
            X_sub = X[indexSet[j*batch_size:(j+1)*batch_size],:]
            y_sub = y[indexSet[j*batch_size:(j+1)*batch_size]]
            if(len(X_sub) > 0):
                grad = (2 * np.mean(X_sub @ theta - y_sub) * X_sub)  # changed line
                theta -= eta * np.mean(grad, axis=0)
    return theta
```

Running the code, I get

```py
print('MSE with GD : ',  MSE(X, y, theta_gd))
print('MSE with SGD: ', MSE(X, y, theta_sgd))
> MSE with GD :  0.07602
  MSE with SGD:  0.05762
```

Answer (score 0):

Each observation has 5 features, and `X` contains 1000 observations:

```py
X = rng.rand(1000, 5) * 10  # X.shape == (1000, 5)
```

Create `y` which is perfectly linearly correlated with `X` (with no distortions):

```py
real_weights = np.array([2.2, 4, -4, 1, 2]).reshape(-1, 1)
real_bias = 0.9
y = X @ real_weights + real_bias  # y.shape == (1000, 1)
```

G.D. implementation for linear regression:

Note:
`w` (weights) is your `theta` variable.
I have also added the calculation of `b` (bias).

```py
def GD(X, y, eta=0.1, n_iter=20):
    # Initialize weights and a bias (all zeros):
    w = np.zeros((X.shape[1], 1))  # w.shape == (5, 1)
    b = 0
    # Gradient descent
    for i in range(n_iter):
        errors = X @ w + b - y  # errors.shape == (1000, 1)
        dw = 2 * np.mean(errors * X, axis=0).reshape(5, 1)
        db = 2 * np.mean(errors)
        w -= eta * dw
        b -= eta * db
    return w, b
```

Testing:

```py
w, b = GD(X, y, eta=0.003, n_iter=5000)
print(w, b)
```

```
[[ 2.20464905]
 [ 4.00510139]
 [-3.99569374]
 [ 1.00444026]
 [ 2.00407476]] 0.7805448262466914
```

Notes:

- Your function `SGD` also contains some error..
- I'm using the [`@` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34142485/14627505) because it's just my preference over `np.dot`.